# Blazor Webasembly on github pages

Tags: html, github, blazor, webassembly

I am trying to publish a Blazor WASM app to Github pages, I believe it is possible because there are many tutorials in the internet they are just very old and don't seem to be working anymore. My solution has a Web Api: "App.Api", and the blazor wasm: "App.Client". Also i am using MudBlazor as a component library. I have the whole solution in a repository, so to be able to publish only the .Client I created a workflow:

```yaml
name: Deploy Blazor Wasm App to GitHub Page
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  deploy-to-github-pages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0.x
      - name: Install .NET WASM Build Tools
        run: dotnet workload install wasm-tools
      - name: Publish .NET Core Project
        run: cd App.Client; dotnet publish -c:Release -p:GHPages=true -o ../dist/Web --nologo
      - name: Commit wwwroot to GitHub Pages
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@3.7.1
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}
          BRANCH: gh-pages
          FOLDER: dist/Web/wwwroot
```

I am very new to github actions so there are many things there I do not really get, but this action works and it is able to deploy without any error. Note that I have to change the directory in one step to be able to publish `run: cd App.Client; dotnet publish -c:Release -p:GHPages=true -o ../dist/Web --nologo`.
The problem is that when i load into the page i get many errors of `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`.
All the resources it is not able to load are:

- MudBlazor.min.css:1
- blazor.webassembly.js:1
- App.Client.styles.css:1
- MudBlazor.min.js:1
- app.css:1
- App.Client.styles.css:1
- app.css:1
- MudBlazor.min.css:1

### What I Have Tried

Somewhare in the internet it said to change `<base href="/">` in `index.html` to the name of my repository but that did not work either.
I've also read many forums but don't seem to apply.
I can't use Azure which would be my preference, but i was assinged to do it in Github Pages.

Comment: It can be done - I've done it in the past, but it required a lot of fiddling. Also remember that GitHub will only host static sites for free so none of your API stuff is going to work when hosted on GitHub. I'm pretty sure [this is the tutorial](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-aspnet-blazor-webassembly-to-github-pages) I used back when I was messing with it.